# Overridden Cart block does not load template

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, overrides

I'm trying to customize a Magento 2.1 cart page both by overriding the Block Cart and accessing some of the overridden elements in a new phtml template.

I hit a roadblock after overriding the Cart block however, as it appears the overridden block in never loading *any* cart form.phtml, custom or otherwise.

I have created the override by creating the app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Cart.php file that extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart {
    public function getContinueShoppingUrl() {
        return 'http://externalurl/from/config';
    }
}
```

I have also created app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml with the configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Cart" />
</config>
```

I know that the overridden block is at least loading, as I can get output from echoing items in the constructor and there appear to be no other errors in the log.  However, when I go to the /checkout/cart/ page, where I expect the checkout details to load I get nothing - just the typical header and footer elements surrounding a blank page.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: please put the code of "Cart.php" file which you override.

Comment: Add this line after your namespace line in block file. use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;   hope it works

Comment: No luck.  Added the line, flushed my cache, but still blank.

Comment: Keep only Block file. I dont think you required di.xml file to override Block. remove "di.xml" file and try again.

Comment: I removed the di.xml file and the page definitely loads, but I do not believe that it is being overridden.  Maybe this is too crude a check, but when I define a constructor and put a 'die' in it, nothing happens unless the di.xml file is configured.

Comment: Additionally, the code posted is the entirety of the files, with the exception of the genericised Vendor\Module

Comment: Check the log files, in system.log or exception.log it's possible to find something

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  I had been checking other logs but didn't think of checking the primary system log.  I'm getting a critical error regarding an invalid template file 'cart.phtml' in module Vendor_Module, which matches with my suspicions.  I'm currently digging around to see if I can clear this error.

Answer (score 0):

In overriding the Cart, the template files are being searched for in the relative path of the new Module, instead of the parent module.  The quick-and-dirty fix I came up with is to copy the contents of the module-checkout's /view/templates/ into /Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/

I suspect there are cleaner ways of doing this, but this method appears functional.

Comment: If you just want to change continue shopping url then just use plugin on that block and create `afterGetContinueShoppingUrl()` method in it.